# How does ngFor differentiate two instances of the same class?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have been reading for many hours a lot of documentation and examples about `ngFor` and **they always do the same**: define the class, export it and iterate it. I put here an example:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<form>

  <input type="text" name="nombre" [(ngModel)]= "nombre"><br/>

  <input type="text" name="apellido" [(ngModel)]= "apellido"><br/>

  <input type="submit" name="registrar" (click)="Register()"><br/>

</form>

<br/>

<p *ngIf="registered; else notregistered">{{message}} con el nombre de {{nombre}} {{apellido}}</p>

<ng-template #notregistered>

  <p>nadie registrado</p>

</ng-template>

<br/>

<br/>

<ul>

<li *ngFor='let entry of entrys'>{{entry.title}}</li>

</ul>
```

```
interface Entrys{
    title:string
}

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Registro';
  message = '';
  registered = false;
  nombre:string = "";
  apellido:string = "";
  entrys:Entrys[];

  constructor(){
    this.entrys=[
      {title:"hola1"},
      {title:"hola2"},
      {title:"hola3"},
      {title:"hola4"},
      {title:"hola5"},
      {title:"hola6"},
    ]
  }

  Register()
  {
    this.registered = true;
    this.message = "user registered"
  }
}
```

My **question** is: if I declare and initialize two differents AppComponent objects with different values, what is `ngFor` going to do? It seems that `ngFor` doesn't differentiate objects according to documentation.

Sorry if my question is not very well written, but I am writing it from my mobile phone and I'm beggining to study Angular.

Comment: I edited the question to correct grammatical errors. I am Spanish hehe

Comment: I don’t understand.. two instances of the same component? So each has its one ngFor and content. Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is the following: ngFor, in my example, is using the attribute entrys, but it doesn't check the object. It is like ngFor doesn't mind the object.

Answer (score 0):

A html file (the template) can't have two component objects. Each component has a set of metadata at the top. In the metadata of the component you declare the templateURL. That is the template file. That code connects the template to the component. The template will always reference the component it is connected to.

In this example "hero-list.component.html" is the template file.

[image]

Image from: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components

Comment: Imagine I have two instances of HeroListComponent in other script: hero1 and hero2. They have different attributes: hero1.name = Tom and hero2.name = Jerry. If I want to use only one of them, but ngFor only use the templateURL, how can ngFor differentiate both? Supose I want to iterate over some atributte of hero1 which is an array

Comment: I understand that confusion here. Angular components are Typescript class. However, to use them you don't make an instance of the class in the typical way. You instead use the selector in the HTML. This makes an instance of the entire component. So the scenario you are referring to would never happen.

Comment: But, then, how does ngFor know the values for the instance ? ngFor is using an instance of the entire component, but I want to use the values of specific instances: hero1 and hero2. I don't understand how. Do you have some link to a blog or another source which explains it in details ? Thanks

Comment: Here is the official documentation about components. https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components